# RecyclerView not transitioning with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, transition

I have a fragment that has a `listview` with a `recyclerview` inside of it. I'm trying to transition into that fragment from different fragments using the `setExitTransition` and the `setEnterTansition` methods. When transitioning to and from other fragments, it transitions fine. However, in this fragment, the `recyclerview` is the only thing not transitioning in the fragment; all other textviews and such is transitioning fine. Why is the `recyclerview` not transitioning? Could it be perhaps due to there being an adapter inside of an adapter? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you manage to have a Recycler inside a ListView? Do they scroll in different directions? Can you post a bit a code please?

Comment: Yes, the ListView scrolls vertically, and inside every row there is a RecyclerView which scrolls horizontally. What code do you want? Code for my adapters?

Comment: Ok. At least the layout

Comment: I can't post "the layout" because it isn't one layout. I have a main layout which has a fragment container in it and in the container I have another layout that contains a listview and I inflate a recyclerview for each row of the listview